# Using a Chrome profile does not work in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io

I am trying to avoid handling signing in by signing in beforehand in my profile.

I am using this code but it still does not load in the profile I have specified. How do I fix this?

```js
const browser = await remote({
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: [
        `user-data-dir=C:/Users/rudra/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome`,
        `profile-directory=Avg`
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked for me

```
  args: [
    'user-data-dir=C:/Users/rudra/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User\ Data',
    'profile-directory=Avg'
  ]
```